# tsql sum of columns within date range

Tags: t-sql, sum, date-range

I have a table with four columns relevant to this question: EventID (int, null), StartDateTime (datetime, null), EndDateTime (datetime, null), DurationInMinutes (int, null)

I want to write a query that will select an additional column with a sum of the total duration of events that have occurred within 7 consecutive days preceding the event, and I'm at a loss as to how to best do that. Right now I'm thinking some sort of SUM of a case statement or LAG, but I can't figure out how to write that. I'm hoping to avoid anything that would need a cte, if only because my query has far too many of those already. Please help?

Comment: Please show us sample data and desired results, otherwise you question is not specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few assumptions made while posting this answer.
Assumptions:

1. Sum to include records even if the eventid is null
2. Sum not to include the records where startdatetime is null
3. Sum not to include the records where enddatetime is null
4. Would there be overlapping records with same event id? (This is not considered)
5. Assumed that the table will be sorted with date and time

```
SELECT *,
       Isnull(SUM(durationinminutes)
                over (
                  ORDER BY startdatetime, enddatetime ROWS BETWEEN unbounded
                preceding
                AND 7
                preceding), 0) AS SevenDayPreviousRunningTotal
FROM   data
WHERE  startdatetime IS NOT NULL
       AND enddatetime IS NOT NULL
```

I would update my answer if the conditions don't match with your requirements.
In that case, please update the question with more details.